# Open another view in new task WPF caliburn.micro c#

Tags: c#, wpf, view, caliburn.micro

I have 2 view in the first(MainView) i select a file and import it, in the second view (BView) show the detail of this file in a datagrid.

This is the first view (MainView):

[image]

This is the second view (BView):
[image]

I want that when I click on "Import" appears on the progressbar and the text, while the second view loads. I would like to open the another view in another TASK but I get this error message:

**"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."**

This is the code of MainViewModel is:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
    public class MainViewModel : Screen
    {
        public string Path{ get; set; }
        public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Import]
        IWindowManager WindowManager { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            Text = "";
        }


        public void Open()
        {
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
            fd.Filter = "Text|*.txt|All|*.*";
            fd.FilterIndex = 1;

            fd.ShowDialog();

            Path= fd.FileName;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Path");
        }


        public void Import()
        {
            if (Percorso != null)
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                Text = "Generate..";
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBusy");
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Text");
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GoNew());

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select file!", "Error", 
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        public void GoNew()
        {
            WindowManager.ShowWindow(new BViewModel(Path), null, null);
            Execute.OnUIThread(() =>
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBusy");
                Text = "";
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Text");
            });
        }         

    }
```

What i can do?

Comment: Could it be to do with `WindowManager.ShowWindow` not being on the UI thread? Looks like everything else is being marshalled to the UI thread - which line throws the error?

Comment: This line :WindowManager.ShowWindow(new BViewModel(Path), null, null);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute your `WindowManager.ShowWindow` on the UI thread since Task.Start() will be on a different thread. Any UI actions should always be marshalled to the UI thread or you get the cross thread exception you mentioned.

Try:

```
    public void GoNew()
    {
        Execute.OnUIThread(() =>
        {
            WindowManager.ShowWindow(new BViewModel(Path), null, null);
            IsBusy = false;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBusy");
            Text = "";
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Text");
        });
    }
```

Edit: try this

```
   public void GoNew()
    {
        var vm = new BViewModel(Path);

        Execute.OnUIThread(() =>
        {
            WindowManager.ShowWindow(vm, null, null);
            IsBusy = false;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBusy");
            Text = "";
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Text");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok. It work ! But why now the Progress bar is visible but does not move ?

Comment: Since you didn't post the B view model code I can only assume that when you create this view model it does some work to import the data, but you are creating your work in the ui thread. You need to process then show the vm, not do both on ui thread

Comment: The loading BView takes 6-7 seconds. However you say that I should not use "Execute.OnUIThread(() =>" ??

Comment: You need to create your view before you show the window. Create view can be outside the execute.onuithread as you want this work to be done on the task thread, then call show in the ui thread, otherwise you are locking the ui thread for several seconds